# Can there be memory contention even if there are no locks?

Tags: c++, multithreading, contention

I am writing a multithreaded code where a bunch of `std::async` calls spawn a fixed number of threads for the duration of the entire program. Each thread works off the same `const BigData` structure on a read-only basis. There are frequent, random reads from `const BigData` but the threads are otherwise totally independent. Can one reasonably expect to get perfect scaling or is there a slowdown to be expected from more memory accesses?

EDIT: After some profiling, this seems to be the culprit:

```cpp
class Point {
  friend Point operator+(const Point& lhs, const Point& rhs) noexcept {
    return Point{lhs.x + rhs.x, lhs.y + rhs.y, lhs.z + rhs.z};
  };
  friend Point operator-(const Point& lhs, const Point& rhs) noexcept {
    return Point{lhs.x - rhs.x, lhs.y - rhs.y, lhs.z - rhs.z};
  };

public:
  Point() noexcept;
  Point(const Real& x, const Real& y, const Real& z) noexcept
    : x{x}, y{y}, z{z} {};

private:
  Real x{0};
  Real y{0};
  Real z{0};
};
```

After refactoring my code to avoid unnecessary calls to `operator+` and `operator-`, I seem to get better scaling.

Comment: There are enough unspecified parameters (read size, behavior w.r.t. caching, anything related to NUMA, etc) that we can't give a clear answer. Your best bet is to run experiments and see how the performance scales.

Comment: I'd be surprised if you saw much slowdown, since the read-only nature of the data should allow each CPU to cache its own local copy of whatever pages it is accessing.  Of course if your CPU cores are sharing a cache, and together they fill up that cache such that they are repeatedly kicking each other's pages out of the cache to load in their own, that would cause some slowdown (relative to the theoretical best performance, anyway).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes there can be a slowdown.  Main memory (RAM) bandwidth is limited, and if you have multiple cores reading a lot of data quickly you may saturate the memory bus.  The maximum memory bandwidth is typically tens of gigabytes per second (see the page for your specific processor, e.g. [i9-9900K](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/186605/intel-core-i9-9900k-processor-16m-cache-up-to-5-00-ghz.html) which shows 41.6 GB/s).

As well, all cores on one physical package share a single L3 cache, so if you are reading some data more than once you may have fewer cache hits as your threads push each others' data out of L3 (which is the largest cache).

If you want to know how much slowdown there is from certain configurations, you have only one choice: **test them**.  Consider adding prefetch instructions to your code if you know ahead of time what memory you are likely to need, especially if your access pattern is non-sequential.

Comment: I began profiling my code. One section section allocates memory (on the stack?) to do some simple arithmetic using a `Point3D` class. For example `(u + v) * (w + x)` creates two temporary `Point3D` objects for the sum. The constructor for `Point3D` was taking up a larger percent of the time in the multithreaded case. Is this one possible cause for a saturated memory bus?

Comment: Show the code of the Point3D constructor.

Comment: Updated. I'm still figuring out how to profile memory on macOS (Big Sur). Valgrind won't work but Instruments.app seems to work. Since my issue seems to be memory saturation, I will look into [Intel's VTune Profiler](https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/tools/oneapi/components/vtune-profiler.html).

Comment: What compiler flags are you using exactly?  I'm especially interested to know your optimization settings.

Comment: I'm using Apple Clang version 12.0.0 with only `-O3` set. I can send you an invite to the repo as it's private only at the moment.

Comment: I've gone ahead and marked this the answer as it's got me on the right track. I realize I still have a lot of optimization to do but there are features which need more attention at the moment.